# Can Excel's ISERROR be used in a cascading manner?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is my original formula

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$B$3:$I$516"),6,FALSE)),"✖",
    IF(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$B$3:$I$516"),6,FALSE)=$D3,
    IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$A$3:$A$516"),
    MATCH($A3,INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$B$3:$B$516"),0))>0,
    INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$A$3:$A$516"),
    MATCH($A3,INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$B$3:$B$516"),0)),"✔"),"✓"))
```

Which will place an X if the value isn't found, the first type of check mark if the criteria matches and the other kind if it's found but the criteria doesn't match.

I learned today that ISERROR shortens the ISNA structure that I've built up by removing the redundant lookup.  How can I use that (or something else) to shorten this formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later use

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$B$3:$I$516")
                             ,6,FALSE)=D3,"✔","✓"), "✖")
```

If using Excel 2003 or earlier use

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH($A3,INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$B$3:$b$516"),FALSE)),"✖",
  IF(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT("'"&G$2&"'!$B$3:$I$516"),6,FALSE)=D3,"✔","✓"))
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of putting the IF inside the IFERROR, thanks!